# Xpath returning NULL for valid Xpath expression

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery, xml-namespaces

I'm using a fairly straightforward Xpath query (below) to query a SQL Server 2008 database column whose values all follow the form of the example (below that). My query returns `NULL` for all rows, rather than the values of the `example` attribute (e.g. "VALUE"), even though the `example` attribute is defined for every row I'm querying.

I've tried declaring the `xsd` and `xsi` namespaces in my Xquery expression, and selecting from multiple different attribute names, but neither had any effect. What am I missing?

**Query**:

```
select ColumnName.value('(/RootNode/@example)[1]', 'nvarchar(15)') [Result]
  from TableName
```

**XML sample node** (actual XML contains many more attributes, which I've omitted):

```
<RootNode xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://intranet"
          example="VALUE">
  <IsValid>true</IsValid>
</RootNode>
```

**Attempted query using namespaces, with same result**:

```
select ColumnName.value('
declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
declare namespace xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

(/RootNode/@example)[1]', 'nvarchar(15)') [Result]
  from TableName
```

Comment: I don't see the namespace mentioned in your query. not `xsi` or `xsd`, but the default set one, `http://intranet`

Comment: @StenPetrov I tried adding those, but it made no difference, so I removed them

Comment: `xsd` and `xsi` won't make difference, the default namespace will. I'm having trouble also decyphering your xpath. Looks like you're looking to retrieve `IsValid` for a `RootNode` that has `@example`, which would be `//RootNode[@example]/IsValid`

Comment: @StenPetrov you're right, it did have to do with the default namespace. I will add an answer shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the default namespace for your xml data and most likely modify the xpath query.

I haven't run this to test but it's my best guess and should get you going:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (N'http://intranet' as intra)
SELECT ColumnName.value('/intra:RootNode[@example]/intra:IsValid[1]', 'nvarchar(15)') [Result]
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Thanks, that's another syntax for what I just arrived at.

Answer (score 4):

This query works. The problem is that the data nodes declare a custom default namespace.

```
select ColumnName.value('
declare default element namespace "http://intranet";

(/RootNode/@example)[1]', 'nvarchar(15)') [Result]
  from TableName
```